# GNUplot 3D plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have this dataset:
(Name of the file containing this dataset is b0-1_g1-0_100000.dat)

```
13,1.0,0.1
1444,1.0,0.2
1612,1.0,0.3
1652,1.0,0.4
1591,1.0,0.5
1661,1.0,0.6
1687,1.0,0.7
1678,1.0,0.8
1703,1.0,0.9
1661,1.0,1.0
25,0.9,0.1
1779,0.9,0.2
1823,0.9,0.3
1831,0.9,0.4
1830,0.9,0.5
1873,0.9,0.6
1834,0.9,0.7
1778,0.9,0.8
1910,0.9,0.9
1894,0.9,1.0
180,0.8,0.1
2063,0.8,0.2
2068,0.8,0.3
2014,0.8,0.4
2065,0.8,0.5
2017,0.8,0.6
2050,0.8,0.7
2065,0.8,0.8
2061,0.8,0.9
1999,0.8,1.0
113,0.7,0.1
2291,0.7,0.2
2309,0.7,0.3
2249,0.7,0.4
2267,0.7,0.5
2297,0.7,0.6
2221,0.7,0.7
2296,0.7,0.8
2381,0.7,0.9
2289,0.7,1.0
450,0.6,0.1
2675,0.6,0.2
2657,0.6,0.3
2650,0.6,0.4
2622,0.6,0.5
2678,0.6,0.6
2511,0.6,0.7
2589,0.6,0.8
2580,0.6,0.9
2674,0.6,1.0
2417,0.5,0.1
3130,0.5,0.2
3160,0.5,0.3
3187,0.5,0.4
3083,0.5,0.5
3196,0.5,0.6
3085,0.5,0.7
3051,0.5,0.8
3075,0.5,0.9
3077,0.5,1.0
3338,0.4,0.1
3822,0.4,0.2
3810,0.4,0.3
3922,0.4,0.4
3884,0.4,0.5
3824,0.4,0.6
3801,0.4,0.7
3719,0.4,0.8
3880,0.4,0.9
3838,0.4,1.0
4950,0.3,0.1
4872,0.3,0.2
4971,0.3,0.3
4808,0.3,0.4
4866,0.3,0.5
4891,0.3,0.6
4838,0.3,0.7
4914,0.3,0.8
5017,0.3,0.9
4834,0.3,1.0
6914,0.2,0.1
6847,0.2,0.2
6783,0.2,0.3
6668,0.2,0.4
6844,0.2,0.5
6914,0.2,0.6
6637,0.2,0.7
6824,0.2,0.8
6793,0.2,0.9
6752,0.2,1.0
11323,0.1,0.1
11173,0.1,0.2
11375,0.1,0.3
11237,0.1,0.4
11282,0.1,0.5
11263,0.1,0.6
11260,0.1,0.7
11318,0.1,0.8
11282,0.1,0.9
11279,0.1,1.0
```

And i want to plot it in gnuplot:

```
set datafile separator ','
splot 'b0-1_g1-0_100000.dat'u 1:2:3
                                   ^
       All points z value undefined
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?
I am using gnuplot version 5.2 patchlevel 8

Comment: It works for me on the sample data.

Comment: Would you mind showing me a picture please? Because i have no idea what iam doing wrong.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GoliqBX

Comment: Yeah that is exactly how I want mine to look. Thanks for the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It seems like there was an encoding problem. But now it works fine.